# Problem with the GFnotation package

Tags: packages

I'm trying to use the `GFnotation` package to be able to use Frege's notation in *Be­griff­ss­chrift*, but I get the following error in the `GFnotation.tex` file:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\bstenpoint ->\scriptfont \itfam 
                                 =\sevenit \scriptscriptfont \itfam =\fiveit...
l.189 \bstenpoint
```

Just in case it matters, I'm using Overleaf to compile. Anyone know away to solve this problem?

Comment: It is not a LaTeX package, but should be used with plain TeX and AMS-TeX. See `begriff` and `grundgesetze` for LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Oh, thanks, I should have noticed that. I ended up using `grundgesetze`, it looks better (even though I prefer `GFnotation`'s commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GFnotation` macro package is for plain TeX. This doesn’t mean it cannot work in LaTeX, but some surgery is necessary anyway.

<sup>For lack of examples it’s not even possible to diagnose your reported error.</sup>

There are two LaTeX packages: `begriff` and `grundgesetze`, the latter seems more actively maintained.